# How to calculate TP, TN, FP and FN with spark and scala when I have predictions and ground truth file ( original graph )?

Tags: algorithm, scala, apache-spark, evaluation, precision-recall

I have a dataframe which represents a graph. It has the following structure:

a,b
b,c
b,d

This graph represents a co-authorship network. I have run brute force check fore every node to each other node and if the adge (e.g. a,b => nodes are papers) has a jaccard similarity > from a given threshold, I am keeping this edge to my results. My results is a same structure dataframe as the first one.

I want now to get the number of TP, TN, FP and FN for my predictions in order to calculate precision, recall, accuracy and F1 score. How can I get these values?

Is there any way to calculate F1 score with scala only with these two dataframes (originalDF and predictionsDF)?

Thnak you!

Comment: Have you try with MulticlassMetrics from mlib?

Comment: I dont have a model to use MulticlassMetrics. Its only data frame operations and transformations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have a DataFrame with the columns "label" and "prediction", then you can compute TP, TN, FP, FN with the filter method like this:

```
val TP = predictions.filter($"prediction"===1 && $"label"===$"prediction").count()
val FP = predictions.filter($"prediction"===1 && $"label"=!=$"prediction").count()
val TN = predictions.filter($"prediction"===0 && $"label"===$"prediction").count()
val FN = predictions.filter($"prediction"===0 && $"label"=!=$"prediction").count()
```

[image]